# can anybody give me realtime sqlite example

Tags: java, android

Actually earlier i was working as a Web Developer so i am not able to imagine mobile database. It has become complicated for me

I mean to say steps like given as below,
CheckDBExist
Create it if does not exist,
Insert when told to,
Update when required and,
anything u would like to suggest me as a beginner

Example with multiple fields addition in a table and multiple values entering into it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify sqlite is not a mobile database, but a light-weight (small sized) database with a structure that makes it well suitable for mobile devices. You might not notice it but you might have actually used a sqlite database already (on the frontend) when you saved bookmarks on your browser (in Firefox & Opera that is)

[Here's a link](http://my.opera.com/jsharma/blog/sqlite-sample-run-for-quickstart) to what I've used as reference and starting point to learn it (although not specifically for a java environment).

Comment: Ohhh i am sorry, meant to say not getting structure of mobile databases and i haven't used sqlite as before so don't have much knowledge over but i am sorry for calling it as mobile database even after reading few articles on it. By d way thanks for guiding me.. Thank u very much..